# Apply css to immediate child element

Tags: css

```css
background-color: yellow;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<div>
  <p>Paragraph 1 in the div.</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2 in the div.</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3. Not in a div.</p>
  <p>Paragraph 4. Not in a div.</p>
</div>
```

I want to apply background color for only the first `<p></p>` element inside the div.

tried some css selectors,couldn't get the expected result. Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS selector for first element with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)

Comment: @Andreew4x4 w3schools are not the W3C. They have no affiliation whatsoever.

Comment: First of all, there are already dozen questions like that: stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/… Consider taking W3scools CSS tutorial: - https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp Useful links at this topic: 
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Comment: @Turnip i've re-comment. You are completly right! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

```css
div>p:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Paragraph 1 in the div.</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2 in the div.</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3. Not in a div.</p>
  <p>Paragraph 4. Not in a div.</p>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57otsfwd/)